# Increment counter in TikZ

Tags: tikz-pgf, counters

How to increment counter in TikZ using code below:

```
\newcounter{ga} %counter
\setcounter{ga}{1}
\begin{tikzpicture}
    \foreach \t in {1,...,10}{
      \pgfmathparse{Mod(\t,2) == 1 ? 1 : 0}
      \ifnum\pgfmathresult > 0
         \ga = \ga + 1
      \fi
\end{tikzpicture}
```

In line 4 I need something similar to `\ga = \ga + 1`.

Comment: What is `\ga`? A TeX counter? A macro expanding to a number?

Comment: Yes, \ga is counter.

Comment: Then maybe you could post a complete MWE.

Comment: `\stepcounter{ga}`?

Comment: `\stepcounter{ga}` should do the trick.

Comment: \newcounter{ga}    %novo contador
\setcounter{ga}{1} %valor inicial do contador
\begin{tikzpicture}[>=latex]
\foreach \t in {1,...,10}{
 \node at (\t,0) {\thega};
 \pgfmathparse{Mod(\t,2) == 1 ? 1 : 0}
    \ifnum\pgfmathresult > 0
   \pgfmathsetcounter{ga}{\thega+1} %soma 1 no contador
   \setcounter{ga}{\thega} %redefine o contador
  \pgfmathparse{Mod(\thega,2) == 0 ? 1 : 0}
   \ifnum\pgfmathresult > 0
    \pgfmathsetcounter{ga}{0} %soma 1 no contador
    \setcounter{ga}{\thega} %redefine o contador
  \fi
 \fi
}
\end{tikzpicture}

Comment: You don't need that. As commented above, `\begin{tikzpicture}\foreach \t in {1,...,10}{\pgfmathparse{Mod(\t,2) ==1?1:0}\ifnum\pgfmathresult>0\stepcounter{ga}\else\fi\node at (\t,0){\number\value{ga}};}\end{tikzpicture}` is sufficient.

Comment: @percusse: Why don’t you make a real answer of your comment?

Comment: I think it's @Caramdir's answer :p

Comment: One thing to note here is that the solution needs to be one that increments the counter *globally*.  LaTeX's `\stepcounter` does this automatically, other methods might need it to be explicitly made global.

Answer (score 9):

```
\documentclass{minimal}
\usepackage{tikz}
\newcounter{ga}\setcounter{ga}{1}

\begin{document}

\foreach \t in {1,...,10}{\ifodd\t \stepcounter{ga}\fi}
\thega
\end{document}
```

and an example with placing the value in a node:

```
\documentclass{minimal}
\usepackage{tikz}
\newcounter{ga}\setcounter{ga}{0}
\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture}
\foreach \t in {1,...,10}{\ifodd\t \stepcounter{ga}\fi}
\node [circle,draw] (a) at (0:1) {\thega};
\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

Comment: This doesn't work in a `tikzpicture` environment.

Comment: see edited answer

Answer (score 8):

It's not really a question about TikZ but about the package `pgffor` and `pgfmath`. 
With Tikz I prefer to use the TeX's macros here `\newcount`, it's more natural if you use `\ifdim`.

**update**

I forgot that I'm the author of Integer arithmetics functions in pgfmath, It's possible to use `isodd`. But `\ifodd` from Herbert's answer is the correct way with `\newcount`.

It's perhaps important to develop the difference between the answers. I feel reticent about mixing TeX's macros and LaTeX's macros.

1) It's  important to notice  that LaTeX’s counters are set globally.

2) The need to use the lower-level TeX system is not obvious but the spirit of TikZ and here for the macro `\foreach`, it's to work if it's possible locally. The difference is that TeX sets count registers locally. So to do a global assignment you have to do it deliberately like with  `\global\advance\ga by1` in my code.

A good document **(tex-counts-and-latex-counters)** is [here](http://www.texdev.net/2009/11/17/tex-counts-and-latex-counters/) from **Joseph Wright**

```
\documentclass[11pt]{article}
\usepackage{tikz}    % or \usepackage{pgffor,pgfmath}  pgf 2.1cvs

\begin{document}
\newcount\ga
\ga=1 %

\foreach \t in {1,...,10}{%
%\pgfmathparse{Mod(\t,2)==1?1:0}
  \pgfmathparse{isodd(\t)}  
\ifnum\pgfmathresult>0 \global\advance\ga by1 \fi
}

\the\ga
\end{document}
```

Result : 6