# Increment/Decrement variables in TikZ

Tags: tikz-pgf

I need to increment/decrement variables in TikZ, i.e., I have

`\def\a{0}`

and then I need to perform

`\a=\a-1.5;`

The code compiles, but it does not change the value of the variable `\a`.

How do I do this?

Comment: In which context are you trying to do this? Do you need a loop, for example? Please elaborate a little more.

Comment: @GonzaloMedina No. I do not need a loop. I am making a drawing in TikZ and the variable stores the coordinates of the center of a piece of the drawing and relative to this, I need to draw the rest.

Comment: Simply having `\a=\a-1.5;` in a TikZ picture doesn’t do anything. (Such text is usually simply discarded as TikZ installs some sort of null font as it simply expands to `0=0-1.5;`.) If you want to use the result of that calculation inside of TikZ you mostly can simply say `\edef\a{\a-1.5}` as TikZ evaluates nearly everything again anyway. Otherwise you need to do `\pgfmathsetmacro\a{\a-1.5}`.

Comment: @Qrrbrbirlbel Thanks! `\edef` is the one I was looking for! Could you add that as an answer? I will accept it.

Comment: I think you are doing something inefficient. If you include your use case then it will be much easier to show how to use relative coordinates.

Comment: @percusse It is interesting that you say that I am doing something inefficient without even looking at what I am doing. All I want is to update the coordinates, as I draw some 6 different pictures and I know only the relative distance between them (these distances are not equal) in a sequential order.

Comment: I said it because you can use the `++(..)` and `+(..)` operators and the whole `calc` for all kinds of relative and incremental computations

Comment: possible duplicate of [Increment counter in TikZ](http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/61072/increment-counter-in-tikz)

Comment: @ColeJohnson Except counters can hold non-integer values.

Answer (score 20):

There's not much to go on in your question.  So, I'll do my best here.
There are several approaches you can take.  You wanted to decrement `\a`; I increment it in the following examples to visually emphasis how the effects are taking place and being used:  just make the necessary changes for decrementing.

The first is to combine a use of `\pgfmathparse` with `\edef`

[image]

code for above image:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{calc}
\begin{document}

Use \verb`\pgfmathparse` together with \verb`\edef`

\begin{tikzpicture}
  \edef\mya{0}
  \pgfmathparse{\mya+1.5}
  \edef\mya{\pgfmathresult}
  \node[circle,draw] at (\mya,\mya) {\mya};
\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

If you want to remember the changed macro outside of the `tikzpicture` then you can use `\xdef`

[image]

code for above image:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{calc}
\begin{document}

To remember outside of the picture use \verb`\xdef`

\begin{tikzpicture}
  \edef\mya{0}
  \pgfmathparse{\mya+1.5}
  \xdef\mya{\pgfmathresult}
  \node[circle,draw] at (\mya,\mya) {\mya};
\end{tikzpicture}

\verb`\mya`=\mya

\end{document}
```

You can use a `\foreach` loop with the above tricks:

[image]

code for above image:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{calc}
\begin{document}

If used within a \verb`\foreach` loop, you have several choices:

Use \verb`\xdef`

\begin{tikzpicture}
  \edef\mya{0}
  \foreach \x in {1,2,...,8}
  {   
      \pgfmathparse{\mya+1.5}
      \xdef\mya{\pgfmathresult}
      \node[circle,draw,inner sep=\mya pt] at (\mya*0.50cm,\mya*0.25cm) {\makebox[0pt]{\mya}};
  }
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

Better yet, you can use `evaluate=\x as ...`

[image]

code for above image:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{calc}
\begin{document}

Using \verb`evaluate=\x as ...`

\begin{tikzpicture}
  \edef\mya{0}
  \foreach \x [evaluate=\x as \mya using \x*1.5] in {1,2,...,8}
  {   
      \node[circle,draw,inner sep=\mya pt] at (\mya*0.5cm,\mya*0.25cm) {\makebox[0pt]{\mya}};
  }
\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

Finally, if you need to remember the value outside of the `\foreach` loop, you can do something like:

[image]

code for above image:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{calc}
\begin{document}

Using \verb`evaluate=\x as ...` and remembering

\begin{tikzpicture}
  \edef\mya{0}
  \foreach \x [evaluate=\x as \mya using \x*1.5] in {1,2,...,8}
  {   
      \node[circle,draw,inner sep=\mya pt] at (\mya*0.5cm,\mya*0.25cm) {\makebox[0pt]{\mya}};
      \xdef\remembermya{\mya}
  }
  \edef\mya{\remembermya}
  \node at (0,0) {\mya};
\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

This should probably be enough to get you started.  If you could post a more thorough MWE illustrating how you're trying to use `\a`, then I could probably  give you a more complete answer.

You could also take a rather different approach using coordinate arithmetic:

[image]

code for above image:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{calc}
\begin{document}

Using \verb`calc` package to perform coordinate arithmetic: \verb`($(0,0)+\x*(<coordinate>)$)` 

\begin{tikzpicture}
  \coordinate (myinc) at (1.5*0.5cm,0.25cm);
  \foreach \x  in {1,2,...,8}
  {   
      \pgfmathparse{\x*1.5}
      \edef\mya{\pgfmathresult}
      \node[circle,draw,inner sep=\mya pt] at ($(0,0)+\x*(myinc)$) {\makebox[0pt]{\mya}};
  }
\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

Comment: Where do I can look for his to use `\def`, `\xdef`, and `\edef`? They all seem LaTeX macros used for something else in TikZ.

Comment: @Atcold I'm unclear about what you're asking.  But there are a number of posts on this site about how to use these commands.  See for example: [What are the differences between \def, \edef, \gdef and \xdef?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/353139/22413) and the link to the duplicate.