# What are the differences between \def, \edef, \gdef and \xdef?

Tags: tex-core

I am a LaTeX guy, slowly working into the miracles of TeX.

Can anybody tell me the differences between `\def`, `\edef`, `\gdef` and `\xdef`?

Where shall I use which, what are the pros and cons?  Or is it suspected to be unclean code, if I mix TeX commands in LaTeX?

Please give a short example, of how to use the command.

Comment: I can recommend 'Notes on Programming in TeX' written by Christian Feuersänger, which gives a lot of insights on this in a short and easy-to-read text.

Comment: @HenriMenke thank you for your comment, that is a phantastic Q&A.  But it does not cover `\gdef` and `\xdef`.

Comment: @pschulz: thank you also very much.  You ment http://pgfplots.sourceforge.net/TeX-programming-notes.pdf?

Comment: Yes, exactly! Sorry for not providing the link, i'm just so used to using `texdoc`, so it's a simple `texdoc programming` for me.

Comment: @Jan `\gdef` (`\xdef`) is merely a shorthand for `\global\def` (`\global\edef`), so the question about these can be reduced to `\def` and `\edef`.

Comment: @HenriMenke: Thank you again for that information.  Therefore, you are right, my question is a duplicate to your given Link.

Answer (score 39, accepted):

There are no pros and cons: `\def` and `\edef` perform different tasks. With

```
\def<cs><parameter text>{<replacement text>}
```

you define `<cs>` to look for its arguments (if any) and to be replaced by `<replacement text>`, which is not interpreted in any way at definition time. With

```
\edef<cs><parameter text>{<replacement text>}
```

the replacement text is fully expanded at definition time.

For instance, if we have

```
\def\aaa{aaa}
\def\bbb{x\aaa}
\edef\ccc{y\aaa}
\def\aaa{AAA}
```

a call like

```
\bbb \ccc
```

would produce

> xAAAyaaa

because the replacement text of `\ccc` is what remains after full expansion, so `\edef\ccc{y\aaa}` is the same as `\def\ccc{yaaa}`.

Note that the expansion in `\edef` is done *at definition time*, so parameter tokens like `#1` and so on will be untouched.

A less silly example: if you want that `\thissection` expands to the value of the `section` counter *at the time the command is defined*, you have to say

```
\edef\thissection{\thesection}
```

because this “freezes” the value by doing the expansion at definition time. To the contrary, with `\def\thissection{\thesection}` the macro `\thissection` would print the current section number.

LaTeX has the variant `\protected@edef` that avoids some quirks with “robust macros”, so something like `\protected@edef\cs{\textbf{a}}` works whereas `\edef\cs{\textbf{a}}` wouldn't (there's plenty of examples on the site).

About `\gdef` and `\xdef` there's not much to say: the former is completely equivalent to `\global\def` and the latter to `\global\edef` (assuming primitive meaning of `\global`, of course). LaTeX has `\protected@xdef`.

Comment: Thank you @egreg.  This is again a very informative and helpful answer.  I still have to fiddle about `\global`.  :-)

Comment: @Jan -- `\global` simply means that the definition persists when the current group closes, instead of the pre-group definition being restored.

Comment: @barbarabeeton thank you.  I added an answer to the [original question](http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/451/when-to-use-edef-noexpand-and-expandafter), as I did a search with all four `\?def`s and did not find an answer.  Now it should be found in either way.  I am personally glad, I finally learned about that TeX stuff.  Next target: what is `\long` good for?

Comment: @Jan -- a separate question about the meaning of `\long` could be useful; i couldn't find any, although it's not easy to look for.  i did find this: [Is there a simple way to retroactively add the \long prefix to a macro's definition?](http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/24240/579), but it presupposes that someone already knows the meaning.  actually, the meaning is simple: a `\long` macro can include a paragraph break, whereas a macro that is not `\long` will throw an error if it encounters `\par` or a blank line.