# Unable to reuse variable using \pgfmathsetmacro

Tags: tikz-pgf, errors, compiling, pgfmath, compilation-error

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}
\begin{document}

\newcommand\routine[1] {
    \pgfmathsetmacro\temp{0}
    \foreach[parse=true][remember=\temp] \i in {1,...,#1} {
        \pgfmathsetmacro\temp {
            \pgfmathparse{\temp+\i}\pgfmathresult
        }
    }
    \temp
}

\routine{5}
\end{document}
```

I created a command that prints the nth triangular numbers. First I set `\temp` to 0 then I add `\i` the ith time the loop is entered. Everytime `\temp` is incremented it is updated. I added `[remember=\temp]` so that it is not lost after each iteration. Then after the end of the loop the result should be printed. Instead I am met with a `! Incomplete \iffalse; all text was ignored after line 16.` error. How should I fix this problem?

Comment: Macros set in a `\foreach` loop are defined locally and are forgotten as soon as the loop ends.

Comment: Besides what @egreg said you also have `\pgfmathparse` inside `\pgfmathsetmacro`. That is not correct. Just do `\pgfmathsetmacro\temp{\temp+\i}` (and then what ever else you need to do with `\temp`). In this case, I'd rather use the function `(#1)*(#1+1)/2`.

Answer (score 1):

Welcome to TeX.SE!!!

You can remember a local variable with the option `\global` as in `\global\edef` or, equivalently, `\xdef`. See, for example, this post: [What are the differences between \def, \edef, \gdef and \xdef?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/353138/what-are-the-differences-between-def-edef-gdef-and-xdef).

So, you can do something like the following code:

```tex
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}

\newcommand\routine[1]
{%
  \pgfmathsetmacro\myfinaltemp{0}%
  \foreach\i in {1,...,#1}
  {%
    \pgfmathtruncatemacro\temp{\myfinaltemp+\i}%
    \xdef\myfinaltemp{\temp}% <-- remember \myfinaltemp, \xdef = \global\edef
  }%
  \myfinaltemp%
}

% anotehr, simpler version
\newcommand{\mytriangle}[1]{\pgfmathparse{int(#1*(1+#1)/2)}\pgfmathresult}

\begin{document}
\noindent
\foreach\j in  {1,...,10}
  {\routine{\j} = \mytriangle{\j}\\}
\end{document}
```

Which produces:

[image]

Answer (score 0):

I believe that `\foreach` is not the best tool for this job.

But you might do it: the printing should be inside the loop, at the last step and you want `int`.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{pgffor}

\newcommand\routine[1]{%
  \pgfmathsetmacro\temp{0}%
  \foreach[parse=true][remember=\temp] \i in {1,...,#1} {%
    \pgfmathsetmacro\temp{int(\temp+\i)}%
    \ifnum#1=\i\relax\temp\fi
  }%
}

\begin{document}

\routine{5}

\end{document}
```

Here's an expandable implementation.

```
\documentclass{article}

\makeatletter
\newcommand{\triangular}[1]{%
  \@triangular{0}{0}{#1}%
}
\newcommand{\@triangular}[3]{%
  % #1 is the current step
  % #2 is the accumulated total
  % #3 is the step we want to get at
  \ifnum#1=#3
    \expandafter\@firstoftwo
  \else
    \expandafter\@secondoftwo
  \fi
  {\the\numexpr#2+#1}%
  {\expanded{\noexpand\@triangular{\the\numexpr#1+1}{\the\numexpr#2+#1}{#3}}}%
}
\makeatother

\begin{document}

\triangular{0}\par
\triangular{1}\par
\triangular{2}\par
\triangular{3}\par
\triangular{4}\par
\triangular{5}\par
\triangular{6}

\edef\test{\triangular{10}}
\texttt{\meaning\test}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Without `\expanded` a slightly more complicated version is needed

```
\newcommand{\@triangular}[3]{%
  % #1 is the current step
  % #2 is the accumulated total
  % #3 is the step we want to get at
  \ifnum#1=#3
    \expandafter\@firstoftwo
  \else
    \expandafter\@secondoftwo
  \fi
  {\the\numexpr#2+#1}%
  {\expandafter\@triangular
      \expandafter{\the\numexpr#1+1\expandafter}%
      \expandafter{\the\numexpr#2+#1}{#3}%
  }
}
```

Finally, the `expl3` code:

```
\documentclass{article}

\ExplSyntaxOn

\NewExpandableDocumentCommand{\triangular}{m}
 {
  \acter_triangular:nnn { 0 } { 0 } { #1 }
 }

\cs_new:Nn \acter_triangular:nnn
 {
  % #1 is the current step
  % #2 is the accumulated total
  % #3 is the step we want to get at
  \int_compare:nTF { #1 = #3 }
   {% reached
    \int_eval:n { #2 + #1 }
   }
   {% restart
    \acter_triangular:een { \int_eval:n { #1 + 1 } } { \int_eval:n { #2 + #1 } } { #3 }
   }
 }
\cs_generate_variant:Nn \acter_triangular:nnn { ee }

\ExplSyntaxOff

\begin{document}

\triangular{0}\par
\triangular{1}\par
\triangular{2}\par
\triangular{3}\par
\triangular{4}\par
\triangular{5}\par
\triangular{6}

\edef\test{\triangular{10}}
\texttt{\meaning\test}

\end{document}
```